# Exception date import mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem with mongo import. I  want to import a collection *.json but I haven't managed it work. Mongo show me the next text:

```
exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: code FailedToParse:   FailedToParse: Date expecting integer milliseconds: offset:183.
```

I have written:

```
  mongoimport --db alerts --collection transactions --file transactions.json
```

Anybody knows the problem?

Comment: how many documents are present in the collection transactions?

Comment: The JSON is malformed at offset 183, like the error says. That offset will be close to the start. Can you post samples of the JSON?

Comment: The collection has 2 documents. The problem was my version of mongo. I solved it with the new version 2.6.1